# Nextjs: getServerSideProps is showing a blank page instead of redirecting to 404

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a dynamic page which shows the details of a product, the external server will return 404 if the requested product is not found, The problem is getServerSideProps shows a blank page  instead of redirecting to 404

Here is the code:

```js
// pages/[slug].tsx

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({
  params,
  res,
}) => {
  const { product, relatedProducts } = await getProductDetail(
    params?.slug as string
  );

  if (res.statusCode === 404) {
    return {
      redirect: { destination: "/404", permanent: false },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      product,
      relatedProducts,
    },
  };
};
```

I tried also to use `notFound` property

```js
if (res.statusCode === 404) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    };
  }
```

This is the first time I encountered the problem since server redirection was working pretty fine in other (static) pages

Help is much appreciated

Comment: have you solved this issue so far ?

Answer (score 0):

From NextJS 10 onwards, you don't have to return your 404 page explicitly thanks to the new flag notFound: true. You can use it at getStaticProps and getServerSideProps to auto trigger the default 404 page or your own custom 404 page as well.

```
// pages/[slug].tsx

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({
  params,
  res,
}) => {
  const { product, relatedProducts } = await getProductDetail(
    params?.slug as string
  );


  const data = await res.json()

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }
  // if (res.statusCode === 404) {
    // return {
      // redirect: { destination: "/404", permanent: false },
    // };
  // }

  return {
    props: {
      product,
      relatedProducts,
    },
  };
};
```

**Doc References**

- [notfound Support on Nextjs10](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10#notfound-support)
- [notfound on getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview#getstaticprops-static-generation)
- [notfound on getserversideprops](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)
- [Custom 404 Page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#404-page)

Comment: I've already included that solution in my post above and it did not work,

Comment: You are using `res.statusCode` instead of that try to use `const data = await res.json()

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }` let me know if it works or not, thanks

Comment: yes i tried that and many things inside if statement but still no luck